# Se puede agregar una nueva fila a un datatable y ese mismo editar y mandarse a bd?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

buenas tardes, quiero hacerles una consulta, hay alguna forma de que en un DataTable por medio de un botón se agregue una fila nueva y esa misma fila se pueda llenar con información, todo el datatable se llena con informacion de la BD, basicamente es ir llenando una lista principal (que es donde llega toda información), para que mas o menos me de a entender quiero hacer algo similar a lo de esta pagina:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/addRow.xhtml

Espero y me puedan brindar su opinion y si hay forma podría por favor brindarme tips de como poder hacerlo, saludos y quedo al pendiente.

Comment: ¡Hola!

Puedes hacer lo que dices, el problema a resolver es obtener solo las filas nuevas que se insertaron en la base de datos y agregarlas a la lista que ya tienes en el managed bean. O bien puedes recargar toda la lista completa cada vez. O también puedes paginar los resultados. O puedes usar el componente de polling para refrescar la tabla cada x minutos. O puedes hacerlo con web sockets. En fin, tienes muchas posibilidades y la solución a implementar dependerá básicamente de la cantidad de datos a mostrar y cuan frecuentemente se modifican los mismos.

¿Cual es tu duda exactamente?

Comment: Si se puede, ¿podrías poner tu tabla y tu managed bean?

Comment: Hola amigos, ya pude realizar todo lo que puse en mi pregunta, mas adelante que acabe les pondré todo lo que hice, para que alguien que igual lo necesita se pueda guiar, saludos

Answer (score 0):

lo prometido es deuda, les dejo todo el codigo que realicé durante todo:

```
//Agrega nueva fila:
    public void onAddNew() {
        //Se crea una nueva instancia del objeto ControlVersionesDTO
        ControlVersionesDTO agregarFila = new ControlVersionesDTO();
        //Cuando se da en nuevo, se crea una fila y le seteamos el valor 1, que quiere decir que será un insert
        agregarFila.setStatusAccionInsertUpdate(1);
        agregarFila.setCve_version(0);
        //Dicha fila se agrega a la lista filtrada por medio del objeto agregarfila
        listControlVersionesFiltradas.add(agregarFila);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultarNuevo()");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultarEliminar(" + (listControlVersionesFiltradas.size() - 1) + ")");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("data_table");
    }

  //Metodo para cancelar edición de un registro
    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        ControlVersionesDTO cancelarEdit = ((ControlVersionesDTO) event.getObject());//Se habilita la fila que se seleccionó
        cancelarEdit.setStatusAccionInsertUpdate(0);//Regresamos el valor por defecto a cero para que en el sp de insertUpdate no lo pele XD

        System.out.println("Hola Cancelé");
        System.out.println("Status updateInsert..." + cancelarEdit.getStatusAccionInsertUpdate());

    }

    //Metodo para editar registros del dataTable
    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {

        //System.out.println("Entre editar...");
        ControlVersionesDTO editFila = ((ControlVersionesDTO) event.getObject());

        if (editFila.getStatusAccionInsertUpdate() == 0) {
            editFila.setStatusAccionInsertUpdate(2);
        }

        System.out.println("Hola Edite fila");
        System.out.println("Status updateInsert..." + editFila.getStatusAccionInsertUpdate());

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("mostrarIconoGuardar()");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("formulario:data_table");

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultarEliminar(" + (listControlVersionesFiltradas.size() - 1) + ")");
    }
```

El método donde guardo y previamente valido:

```
 public void SaveRegistros() throws SQLException {
        for (int i = 0; i < listControlVersionesFiltradas.size(); i++) {
            //listaToJson.clear();

            System.out.println("json888..." + listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).getFw_to_update());
            if (listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).getFw_to_update() == null || listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).getFw_to_update() == "" || listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).getActual_fw() == "" || listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).getDevice_version() == "" || listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).getVersion_id() == "") {

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error: ", "Favor de completar las columnas faltante."));
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaControlDevice");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultarEliminar(" + (listControlVersionesFiltradas.size() - 1) + ")");
                return;

            }

        }
        //RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultarEliminar(" + (listControlVersionesFiltradas.size() - 1) + ")");
        int cve_device;

        cve_device = controlVersion.getCve_device();//Obtengo el valor del objeto lleno y se lo asigno a la variable cve_device
        //cve_version = controlVersion.getCve_version();
        System.out.println("cve..." + cve_device);
        //System.out.println("cveversion..." + cve_version);

        for (ControlVersionesDTO item : listControlVersionesFiltradas) {
            System.out.println("yyyyyy..." + item.getCve_version());

            if (item.getCve_device() == 0) {
                item.setCve_device(cve_device);
            }

        }

        Gson gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String jsonFromJavaArrayList = gsonBuilder.toJson(listControlVersionesFiltradas);

        //"NO MOVER" Valida que el usuario le dé en guardar sin ingresar registros y que esté vacio por completo (0 registros).
        if (listControlVersionesFiltradas.size() <= 0) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error: ", "No hay registros que guardar."));
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaControlDevice");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");

        } //En este else tiene que entrar cuando se hayan hecho todas las validaciones posibles.
        else {
            System.out.println("json from111..." + jsonFromJavaArrayList);
            ResultSet resultado = dao.saveDevice(jsonFromJavaArrayList);//Se obtiene el resultado del Sp y se asigna a la variable

            if (resultado.next() && resultado.getBoolean(2)) {
                System.out.println("Traigo la clave de la versión que voy a insertar..." + resultado.getString(3));
                System.out.println("Traigo true..." + resultado.getString(2));
                System.out.println("Traigo el mensaje de la BD si soy true..." + resultado.getString(1));
                //Se recorre para revisar lista filtrada los estatus de 1 que vienen siendo insert
                for (int i = 0; i < listControlVersionesFiltradas.size(); i++) {
                    if (listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).getStatusAccionInsertUpdate() == 1) {

                        //Se retorna la cve_version por medio de la variable del resultado del parametro 3 que trae la cve
                        listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).setCve_version((resultado.getInt(3)));

                    }
                    //Se setean el StatusAccionInsertUpdate a 0 para que cuando vuelva insertar otro registro, los ceros nos pele
                    listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(i).setStatusAccionInsertUpdate(0);
                }
                System.out.println("Resultado despues del for..." + resultado);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito: ", "Registro Ingresado Satisfactoriamente."));
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaControlDevice");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("cancelar()");

            } else {
                System.out.println("No traigo nada de clave versión" + resultado.getString(3));
                System.out.println("Voy a venir falso..." + resultado.getString(2));//
                System.out.println("Voy a venir null..." + resultado.getString(1));
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No se pudo insertar registro: ", "La Versión ya existe."));
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaControlDevice");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultarEliminar(" + (listControlVersionesFiltradas.size() - 1) + ")");
                //RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("cancelar()");

            }
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("mostrarIconosNewDevice()");
        }

    }
```

Espero y a alguien le sirva, saludos y buena vibra.