# Ayuda, cuando actualizo me inserta de nuevo el registro que actualicé en java server faces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Espero y se encuentren bien, tengo 1 problema:

El problema es que cuando quiero actualizar un registro en vez de que solo se modifique el edite lo inserta de nuevo (el que edite) este es mi código de actualización:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        System.out.println("cve que trae..." + listControlVersionesFiltradas.get(0).getCve_version());
        System.out.println("Entre editar...");
        ControlVersionesDTO editFila = ((ControlVersionesDTO) event.getObject());
        System.out.println("Status Accion Edit..." + editFila.getStatusAccionInsertUpdate());
        for (int i = 0; i < listControlVersionesFiltradas.size(); i++) {
            if (editFila.getDevice_version() == null && editFila.getCve_version() == 0) {
                editFila.setStatusAccionInsertUpdate(1);
                System.out.println("Hey ya cambie a 1 Insert5" + editFila.getStatusAccionInsertUpdate());

            }
        }

        //listControlVersionesFiltradas.add(editFila);
        System.out.println("Hola Edite fila");
        System.out.println("Status updateInsert..." + editFila.getStatusAccionInsertUpdate());

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("mostrarIconoGuardar()");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("formulario:data_table");
    }
```

No tengo la idea de como decirle al java que solo me actualice cuyo registro es el que estoy modificando, espero y me pueda dar a entender, de antemano les agradezco si me pueden ayudar, saludos y quedo al pendiente.

Nota: Si hace falta algo que se necesite con gusto lo pongo, desgraciadamente mi trabajo ya depende de esto :(

Comment: Que objeto quieres actualizar?

Comment: Hola, el objeto que estoy usando es el dice: editFila

Comment: Yo no veo que hagas el update solo que setteas el valor del objeto ControlVersionesDTO editFila = ((ControlVersionesDTO) event.getObject()); en esta linea, solo en memoria quieres hacer?

Comment: Asi es, practicamente lo que quiero hacer es meterle los valores que modifique y guardarlo

Answer (score 1):

Setea el ID que has obtenido del objeto **"ControlVersionesDTO editFila"**. Con ello entenderá que lo que requieres es actualizar el registro ya encontrado.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: El problema es que no se como setear ese valor, ya que siempre viene en 0 y cuando recorro una lista que viene llena pero no lo trae trae

Comment: Debes modificar tu condición, que según entiendo editFila.getCve_version() es el ID único de cada objeto que quieres modificar. Es decir, ese valor que te llega actualmente ya es diferente de "0" o nulo porque ya existe en el correlativo de tu tabla en base de datos.

Algo así:

if (editFila.getDevice_version() != null && editFila.getCve_version() != 0) {
  editFila.setDevice_version(editFila.getDevice_version());
                editFila.setStatusAccionInsertUpdate(1);
            }

Comment: Hola, perdón por tardar en responder ya lo tuve que solucionar de otra forma, en cuando termine con gusto pondré el codigo por si a alguien le sirva, saludos :)

Comment: Hola de nuevo, pondré el link de todo mi proceso, es este: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225724/se-puede-agregar-una-nueva-fila-a-un-datatable-y-ese-mismo-editar-y-mandarse-a-b?noredirect=1#comment422077_225724

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está todo el proceso que realicé en esta pregunta que puse hace unos dias, espero y les sirva, saludos y buena vibra:

[Se puede agregar una nueva fila a un datatable y ese mismo editar y mandarse a bd?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225724/se-puede-agregar-una-nueva-fila-a-un-datatable-y-ese-mismo-editar-y-mandarse-a-b?noredirect=1#comment422077_225724)

Answer (score 0):

Mi sp

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_insert_update_control_versiones(
in_json text)
RETURNS TABLE(mensaje character varying, success boolean, outclaves INTEGER) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
jsonData json;
var_count integer;
var_json json;
var_json_fields json;
var_n integer;
var_mensaje varchar;
var_success boolean:=false;
var_counts integer;
var_count2 integer;
var_count3 integer;
max_idcve_version INT := 0;
--var_outclaves varchar :='';
BEGIN

--RAISE NOTICE 'PRUEBA VALIDACION REPETIDO';
    jsonData := in_json:: json;  
    FOR var_json_fields IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(jsonData)LOOP 
        --evalua si existe el campo device_version del json ingresado en la bd
        IF((var_json_fields->> 'statusAccionInsertUpdate'):: integer =0) THEN
            CONTINUE;
        END IF;    
        IF((var_json_fields->> 'cve_version'):: integer =0) THEN
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cat_device_fota_version 
            WHERE device_version=(var_json_fields->>'device_version')
            AND status='1' 
            INTO var_count2;            
                IF(var_count2>0) THEN
                    var_success:=false;
                    var_mensaje:='No se pudo insertar, existe versión';
                ELSE
                    var_success:=true;
                    var_mensaje:='Se ha insertado registro exitosamente';                    
                    max_idcve_version := (SELECT COALESCE (MAX(cve_version)+1,1) 
                                            FROM cat_device_fota_version);
                    --var_outclaves := max_idcve_version;                                            
                    INSERT INTO cat_device_fota_version(
                    cve_device,
                    cve_version,
                    device_version,
                    version_id,
                    actual_fw,
                    fw_to_update,
                    status,
                    last_update,
                    user_cve)
                    VALUES(
                    ((var_json_fields->>'cve_device')::integer),                
                    max_idcve_version,
                    ((var_json_fields->>'device_version')::character varying),
                    ((var_json_fields->>'version_id')::character varying), 
                    ((var_json_fields->>'actual_fw')::character varying), 
                    ((var_json_fields->>'fw_to_update')::character varying),
                    1,
                    CURRENT_DATE,
                    (var_json_fields->>'user_cve')::character varying);
                            GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n = ROW_COUNT;
                            IF(var_n > 0) THEN
                                var_success=true;
                            ELSE
                                var_success=false;              
                END IF;
        END IF;             
        ELSE    
        IF((var_json_fields->> 'cve_version'):: integer >0)THEN
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cat_device_fota_version 
            WHERE device_version=(var_json_fields->>'device_version') AND cve_version <>(var_json_fields->> 'cve_version'):: integer
            AND status='1' 
            into var_count3;            
                IF(var_count3>0) THEN
                    var_success:=false;
                    var_mensaje:='No se puede actualizar registro ya existe un registro con la misma versión.';
                ELSE
                    var_success:=true;
                    var_mensaje:='Se ha actualizado exitosamente';                   
                            UPDATE cat_device_fota_version 
                                SET device_version=(var_json_fields->>'device_version'),
                                version_id=(var_json_fields->> 'version_id'),
                                actual_fw=(var_json_fields->> 'actual_fw'),
                                fw_to_update=(var_json_fields->> 'fw_to_update')
                                WHERE cve_version=(var_json_fields->>'cve_version'):: integer;  
                                RAISE NOTICE 'variable contador...%',var_counts;
                                GET DIAGNOSTICS var_n = ROW_COUNT;
                                    IF(var_n > 0) THEN
                                    var_success=true;
                                    ELSE
                                    var_success=false;
                                    END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'var inserrt...%',var_json_fields;
    return QUERY SELECT var_mensaje, var_success, max_idcve_version;
END;
$BODY$;
```